# EGit doesn't see Android Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git, egit

I have a git repository (hosted on github) with 6 Android projects. Each project is stored in a separate folder.
Recently I have added one more project. But when I try to import it to workspace (`Git Repositories` tab in Eclipse), EGit and Eclipse do not see that last project (they propose me to import all 5 other projects, but not the 6th one).
Even if I go directly to the `Git Repositories` tab and find my repo there, then go to `Working Directory` down to the folder with my project, then right-click and `Import Projects...` the Wizard says that `no projects found`.
What is the possible problem? Why Eclipse and EGit do not see my 6th project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have eclipse project files (such as .project) been committed on github?

Comment: Where are they located?

Comment: Could you please also give a link to where I can read about eclipse-generated files for a project?

Comment: Eclipse create a .project file and a .settings folder if project specific settings are enabled in $WORKSPACE/$YOUR_PROJECT_HOME. I suppose egit looks for .project files to identify projects and recreate them. Have a look in another Android project directory (PS these files are hidden by default). [Here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fproject_description_file.html) are some more details on .project file

Answer (score 0):

try using GitExtensions or SmartGit instead... You may import the project manually if EGit is not working.